# SSDT find component by id

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Received a warning running a package.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: The package contains data flow components with multiple inputs. Run-time dependencies that exist among these components may increase memory usage and reduce performance. Consider removing the dependency chain for the following component IDs and output IDs: 4436(4518) 4571(4653) 3437(3470) , to improve performance.

Is there a search function to find the component...4436?

Answer (score 1):

The ID doesn't seem to be stored in the DTSX.

It appears that it's based on the position of the component definition within the DTSX.

However it is visible (although not searchable) in Visual Studio:

1. On the DataFlow click on the object
2. In the properties window (press F4)
3. Look for the setting 'ID'

Mke